# Angular 8 dropdown for complex object

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

In my project I am using .net Core 2.2 and Angular 8 for UI.
I want to implement dropdown for complex objects according their id.
When I go to dropdown I want to show for ex: ProjectName according to their Id.

My VirtualMachine class looks like:

```
    public class VirtualMachine
    {            
        public int Id { get; set; }    

        public string Name { get; set; }    

        public string IpAddress { get; set; }    

        public int DiskSize { get; set; }    

        public short CPU { get; set; }    

        public int Ram { get; set; }    

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public VMRole Role { get; set; }
        public VMStatus Status { get; set; }

        public int HypervisorId { get; set; }
        public Hypervisor Hypervisor { get; set; }

        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        public int ManagementId { get; set; }
        public Management Management { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller POST action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVm(VirtualMachine vm)
    {
        if (await _repo.VmExists(vm.Name))
            return BadRequest("VM name already exists");

        vm.Hypervisor = _context.Hypervisors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.HypervisorId == 
        vm.HypervisorId);
        vm.Project = _context.Projects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ProjectId);
        vm.Management = _context.Managements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ManagementId);

        try
        {
            await _context.VirtualMachines.AddAsync(vm);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Postman POST body:

```
{
    "name":"Abstergo",
    "ipAddress":"192.168.0.1",
    "diskSize":25,
    "cpu":16,
    "ram":100,
    "imageUrl":"www.google.com",
    "role":1,
    "status":0,
    "hypervisorId":1,
    "projectId":11,
    "managementId":8
}
```

Angular typecript class:

```
export class VirtualMachine {
    name: string;
    ipAddress: string;
    diskSize: number;
    cpu: number;
    ram: number;
    imageUrl: string;
    role: string;
    status: string;
    projectId: number;
    hypervisorId: number;
    managementId: number;
    projectName: Project;
    managementName: Management;
    hypervisorName: Hypervisor;
}
```

**html code**

```
<div> 
 <select name="select" [(ngModel)]="model.hypervisorId"> 
  <option style="display:none"></option> 
  <option *ngFor="let data of model.Hypervisor" [ngValue]="data.hyperisorId"> {{data.model.hypervisorName}} </option> 
 </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: can please post here the code that you have tried in angular

Comment: <div>
      <select name="select" [(ngModel)]="model.hypervisorId">
                  <option style="display:none"></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let data of model.Hypervisor" [ngValue]="data.hyperisorId">
                    {{data.model.hypervisorName}} </option>
</select>
    </div>

Comment: To clarify, do you want the order determined by the ID? Or do you want the ID displayed as part of the Text on the select list?

Comment: If you want to order the select list by ID, sort it after retrieving the data.
For example: 

Assuming ID is numeric you can use this:

    items.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.id - b.id;
    });

Comment: I would like to show names according to their id. For ex: projectName according to projectId. This data I get from postgre. This 3 tables have relationship with VirtualMachine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `ProjectName` according to their `Id`, then you can sort this array before showing:

```js
let hypervisor = [
    { projectName: "Abstergo 18", projectId: 18 },
    { projectName: "Abstergo 17", projectId: 17 },
    { projectName: "Abstergo 16", projectId: 16 },
];

hypervisor.sort((a, b) => a.projectId - b.projectId);
console.log(hypervisor);
```

So you can sort in `ngOnInit()` method:

```
hypervisor = [
    { projectName: "Abstergo 18", projectId: 18 },
    { projectName: "Abstergo 17", projectId: 17 },
    { projectName: "Abstergo 16", projectId: 16 },
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.hypervisor.sort((a, b) => a.projectId - b.projectId);    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div> 
   <select name="select"> 
       <option style="display:none">empty</option> 
       <option *ngFor="let data of hypervisor" 
           [ngValue]="data.projectId"> 
           {{data.projectName}} 
       </option> 
   </select> 
</div>
```

It can be seen in [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weodhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Situation is I am getting all data from db using resolvers. I need get data from db instead of hardcoding

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov so you can concatenate result data and sort them after concatenation

Comment: @StepUp The above example works perfect for me, But i have another requirement , Want to default one of the value in the complex object array (ie., hypervisor) . How do we achieve that

Comment: @GouthamNithyananda I am glad that it helped to you! Please, read this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . As a good practice It is better to ask new question to simplify the future search of other users.

Comment: @GouthamNithyananda stackoverflow.com/a/63192748/13596406 check this to get a default selected value in dropdown